# Is there a way that I can translate the argseparse module into some type of object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a python runner program and package like so:

The runner program takes in arguments from the command-line and uses argseparse to parse them, like:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()    
parser.add_argument(...
parser.add_argument(...  
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then it sends them into my package module like this:

```
packageObject = PackageModule(params=args)
```

Now I'm making this into a program that does not take in command-line arguments, but I want to keep initialising the PackageObject with that same line.

How can I make something like,

```
args = ()
args.arguments_1 = 'user_name'
```

?

Comment: `argparse.Namespace`, which is the type of the object returned by `parse_args`, isn't significantly different than `class Namespace: pass`.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a new class to store the states of the arguments:

```
class Args(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

args = Args('user_name', 'something else')
packageObject = PackageModule(params=args)
```

If you're creating multiple `args` instances, you may consider using `__slots__` in the class definition since you won't be assigning new attributes on the instance, also making the instances ligthweight:

```
class Args(object):
    __slots__ = ['arg1', 'arg2']
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
```

Comment: If using >= Python 3.3, they could use [`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) which lets them avoid boilerplate, and will look more like the `argparse.Namespace` if they call `print` on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions:

1. Make the `PackageModule` object accept arguments, and unpack the args object `PackageModule(**vars(args))`
2. Just make a lightweight namedtuple
3. Make a lightweight class
4. Pass args as a dict `params=vars(args)`, and substitute for a normal dict

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a list to `argparse.parse_args()` which does not need to come from the command line:

```
args_list = ['-n', '10', 'hello']
args = parser.parse_args(args_list)
```

Then you should be able to run the rest of your script as before.